# Continuous colour of geom_line according to y value

Tags: r, ggplot2

If you look at this

[image]

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=disp,y=mpg,colour=mpg))+geom_line()
```

you will see that the line colour varies according to the corresponding y value, which is what I want, but only section-by-section. I would like the colour to vary continuously according to the y value. Any easy way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possibility which comes to mind would be to use interpolation to create more x- and y-values, and thereby make the colours more continuous. I use `approx` to " linearly interpolate given data points". Here's an example on a simpler data set:

```
# original data and corresponding plot
df <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = c(3, 1, 4))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = y)) +
  geom_line(size = 3)
```

[image]

```
# interpolation to make 'more values' and a smoother colour gradient 
vals <- approx(x = df$x, y = df$y)
df2 <- data.frame(x = vals$x, y = vals$y)

ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = y)) +
  geom_line(size = 3)
```

[image]

If you wish the gradient to be even smoother, you may use the `n` argument in `approx` to adjust the number of points to be created ("interpolation takes place at `n` equally spaced points spanning the interval  [`min(x), max(x)`]"). With a larger number of values, perhaps `geom_point` gives a smoother appearance:

```
vals <- approx(x = df$x, y = df$y, n = 500)
df2 <- data.frame(x = vals$x, y = vals$y)
ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = y)) +
  geom_point(size = 3)
```

Comment: thanks, that does it. I thought of interpolation but didn't know approx() would make it so easy!

Comment: That approx command is golden, solved my (different) problem. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5):

Since [`ggplot2` v0.8.5](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/83598069217e704fdc94c4593f9556cbbf90f61b/NEWS#L964-L965) one can use `geom_line` or `geom_path` with different `lineend` options (right now there are three options: `round`, `butt` and `square`). Selection depends on the nature of the data.

`round` would work on sharp edges (like in given OPs data):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg, color = mpg)) +
  geom_line(size = 3, lineend = "round")
```

[image]

`square` would work on a *more continuous* variable:

```
df <- data.frame(x = seq(0, 100, 10), y = seq(0, 100, 10) ^ 2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = y)) +
  geom_path(size = 3, lineend = "square")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work for you:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

my_mtcars <- 
  mtcars %>%
  mutate(my_colors = cut(disp, breaks = c(0, 130, 200, 400, Inf)))

ggplot(my_mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg, col = mpg)) + 
  geom_line() + facet_wrap(~ my_colors, scales = 'free_x')
```