# Gaps in line when using geom_path with a colour

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a path using `ggplot2` with colour representing a variable. I've included a toy example below.

```r
# Toy data frame
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = (1:100)^2)

# Load libraries
library(ggplot2)

# Plot data
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = y)) + geom_path(size = 10)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-04-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

As you can see, there are lots of gaps in the `geom_path` line. If I use a single colour, say `colour = "black"`, these gaps are not present. How do I produce this plot without those ugly gaps?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Continuous colour of geom_line according to y value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25906018/continuous-colour-of-geom-line-according-to-y-value)

Comment: Thanks @Henrik – I didn't think about it being a broader issue with `geom_line`, so missed that question. Interpolation, as suggested in that answer, solves the problem. I'll leave this question here to provide a route to that solution for those searching specifically for `geom_path`.

Comment: Use this `geom_path(size = 10, lineend = "square")`

Comment: @PoGibas Great solution! Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: I will add it to the linked post as a new answer