# How to add gradual colour fade/change for multiple categories in geom_path

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to show movements of birds using geom_path in ggplot2, where each bird has its own path. I want to show how each bird path changes through time (i.e. the beginning of the path is darker in colour and the end is lighter, or vice versa).

So far, I was able to use geom_path to get a different coloured line for each bird. However, I cannot seem to get a gradual fade or some other colour change to show time progression.

Here is an example of my data:

```
datexample <- data.frame(
  "site" = c("A","B", "A", "B"), 
  "bird" = c("1A","2A"), 
  "week" = c(28, 28, 29, 29),
  "lat" =  c(45.25, 44.75, 45.25, 45.75), 
  "lon" = c(-61.75, -61.25, -62.75, -62.25)
)
datexample
```

And here is an example of the code for the graph:

```
p = ggplot() +
  geom_path(data = datexample, aes(x = lon, y = lat, colour=bird))+
  coord_sf(crs = 4326, xlim = c(-58, -69), ylim = c(40, 48))+
  xlab("Longitude")+
  ylab("Latitude")+
  labs(color='Bird ID')
p
```

Here is what the output looks like:
[image]

Essentially, I want to be able to show the path that the bird moved throughout the weeks sampled (i.e. which point came first, second, etc.)

I am relatively new to R, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think this may get you going: [Continuous colour of geom_line according to y value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25906018/continuous-colour-of-geom-line-according-to-y-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you might indicate direction on a `geom_path`.

One could be to use `ggforce::geom_link2` in place of `ggplot2::geom_path`, allowing gradual shading along the length of the path. Here, I add a "progress" variable showing how far along each bird is along it's total path, and then map that to alpha (transparency). `geom_link2` creates subdivisions inside the path to allow gradual fading within each segment of the path.

```
library(dplyr)
p = ggplot() +
  ggforce::geom_link2(data = datexample %>% 
                       group_by(bird, site) %>%
                       mutate(progress = row_number()/n()),
            aes(x = lon, y = lat, colour=bird, alpha = progress))+
  coord_sf(crs = 4326, xlim = c(-58, -69), ylim = c(40, 48))+
  xlab("Longitude")+
  ylab("Latitude")+
  labs(color='Bird ID')
p
```

[image]

Alternatively, you might add an arrow:

[image]

```
p = ggplot() +
  geom_path(data = datexample, 
            aes(x = lon, y = lat, colour=bird), 
            arrow = arrow(type = "closed", length = unit(0.03, "npc")))+
  coord_sf(crs = 4326, xlim = c(-58, -69), ylim = c(40, 48))+
  xlab("Longitude")+
  ylab("Latitude")+
  labs(color='Bird ID')
p
```

Comment: Thank you! So I used this code for my real data (which has more than 2 points for each bird) and for some reason, the progress bar only has a line at 1.0 and not for the other sections. So the line is just one solid colour. Is there a way to fix this?

The arrow won't work because there are too many points that zigzag all over the place, so a gradual colour fade or colour change is the only way to show it.

Comment: Possible to share a minimal example from one bird with a few points?

Comment: Here is one bird with 5 points
```
datexample <- data.frame(
  "site" = c("A"), 
  "bird" = c("1A"), 
  "week" = c(201728, 201729, 201730, 201731, 201732),
  "lat" =  c(45, 44.75, 45.03, 46.25, 45.89), 
  "lon" = c(-61.75, -61.39, -61.60, -61.96, -61.53)
)
datexample
```

Comment: Hmmm, works ok for me. You might try looking at the output of `datexample %>% group_by(bird, site) %>% mutate(progress = row_number()/n())` to confirm the `progress` variable is calculating right. If so, you might try a thicker line, or adding `n = 500` (or some n > 100) to the geom_link2 call to make it add more points along the interpolation.